# timeout not respected in request.get()

Tags: python, python-requests, timeout

I can't understand why with this code the `requests.get()` returns immediately error and the 10 second timeout is not respected.
If I remove the header parameter, so only `requests.get(url, proxies={"http": proxy, "https": proxy}, verify=False,timeout=10)`,   the timeout is respected and a request is returned successfully or failure if the timeout occurs.
I need to insert headers and a timeout too to test proxies, how to do it?

```
from fake_useragent import  UserAgent
import requests
ua = UserAgent()

#get a list of proxy 

for i in range(1, len(proxies)):
    # Get a proxy from the pool
    proxy = next(proxy_pool)
    print("Request #%d" % i)
    try:
        response = requests.get(url, headers=ua.random(), proxies={"http": proxy, "https": proxy}, verify=False,timeout=10)
        break
    except:
        print("Skipping. Connnection error")
```

Comment: and if you replace the header by headers['User-Agent'] = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686)   AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.27 Safari/537.17" ???

Comment: yes, it works, so now i think ua.random() generates bad user-agents. Do you know any better packages? Or a list of reliable user agents? @GiovaniSalazar

Comment: I replied bellow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with this

```
ua = UserAgent()
header = {'User-Agent':str(ua.random)}
response = requests.get(url, headers=header, verify=False,timeout=10)
```